# File.create shows no errors but doesnt create file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to copy a file from an external drive by reading its contents, creating a new file elsewhere and writing the contents into it. 
My code shows no errors (using MSV) but when I try to 'download' the file, it completes the code but no file is created.

Can anyone help?

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim FileReader As String
        FileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Label32.Text)
        Dim fbd As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        Dim DownloadLocation As String
        If fbd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
            DownloadLocation = fbd.SelectedPath
            File.Create(fbd.SelectedPath & "pandora speedsign log.txt").Dispose()
            File.WriteAllText(fbd.SelectedPath & "pandora speedsign log.txt", FileReader)
            MessageBox.Show("success!!")
        End If
        'File.Create("C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads" & DownloadFileDate & ".txt")
        'File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" & DownloadFileDate & ".txt", FileReader)
  End Sub
```

I've been looking for different ways of creating the file, different ways of writing the file but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It's a mistake to assume the `%UserProfile%` is always in the `C:\Users` folder, or even that `Downloads` is a direct subfolder of `%UserProfile%`. These are can easily be customized. For example business environments will often set the user profile to live on a network share, and lots of gamers will move their downloads folder to a different disk for free up space for games on a faster system drive.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn in the places my software will be used, its almost a guarantee that theyll be correct, but as you can see in the code, theyre comments from stuff i was using but wanted to keep there just in case, im now using a folderbrowserdialog to select the folder, and is giving me no file :/ thanks very much for your advice though!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sorry, i didnt see your answer, thats incredible, thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can significantly simplify the code like this:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog()
    If fbd.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Ok Then Exit Sub

    Dim outputPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, "pandora speedsign log.txt")
    IO.File.Copy(Label32.Text, outputPath)
End Sub
```